# Bushes turn black on certain sides

Tags: unreal-engine4

I recently started using Unreal Engine 4 and tried to make a simple room. However, when I added a subtractive brush or changed the view, I'm not exactly sure, certain sides of my brushes turned black. Now I can't see those sides anymore, no matter in which view mode I am, except for the wireframe mode, where I can still see the edges of my brushes. I assume it's a bug since it started on all brushes simultaneously on different sides. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I already tried rebuilding and changing the view modes, but this didn't help at all.

[scene in unlit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weOFQ.png)

[scene in wireframe mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmT7f.png)

Comment: Moreover my subtractive brush doesn't really work too, but when I change it to be additive it works as intended